# Mod_Proxy with regex redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I have a domainA.com which I would like to redirect it to:

```
domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
```

So the input on the browser should be domainA.com/f7g6f87g and it should make a background redirection to domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=f7g6f87g, but keep the domain on the browser as is.

My virtual host lines are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@address.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir
    ServerName domainA.com
    ServerAlias www.domainA.com
    ProxyPass / https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
    ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12})$ https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
    ProxyPassReverse / https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
    ErrorLog /var/www/dir/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

With the current lines Im able to redirect the domainA.com to the root of domainB.com. But its not what I need. I need the domainA.com to accept only valid ids (?service=shorty_relay&**id=$1**)
I know somehow I have to combine this regex so I can allow only valid id.

```
 ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12})$ https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
```

Any clues how can I make this possible. Im trying to figure this out days now but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `ProxyPass` line. That line works similar to the `Redirect` directive of mod_alias. It means anything after the `/` automatically gets appended to the end of the target URL, excluding query strings. That means `$1` has no bearing in this directive because you're not using a regular expression to capture a match.

The only thing you should need is your `ProxyPassMatch` line:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12})$ https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
```

Additionally, you don't need to include the query string in the `ProxyPassReverse`. This directive is used to "reverse" map redirects sent from domainB.com to a matching URL in domainA.com. So this should be enough:

```
ProxyPassReverse / https://domainB.com/public.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon, but it doesnt seems to work. Im typing domainA.com/f7g6f87g and Im getting a 404 error page. The links https://domainB.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=f7g6f87g its valid 100%. So the problem its still the proxy lines. Any other ideas?